# Wanting to have scrolling comments box pulling from mySQL using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I haven't started on this yet because I'm still pretty new, and I want to be sure there are not any issues with what I'm wanting to accomplish.

In it's simplest form, I want to have a div that will display a text quote that is pulled from a mySQL database.  Every 5 seconds, the quote will fade out and the next will fade in.

Is ajax appropriate for this?  In more detail, I would have a few functions that would:

- pull the first and last name of the
  user from the database
- Convert that to initials: IE: Joe
  Smith would become -J.S.
- Pull the place from the database: IE:
  Dallas, TX
- Pull the quote from the    database:
  IE: Great Job!

Then it'd populate the div (using a fade in) with

```
Dallas, TX:
"Great Job!"
-J.S.
```

My main question is is this a good way to do this?  I don't want to use flash for this task.  Is there a jQuery plugin that will accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.
**nb:** '#comments' is a span INSIDE your comments div.
**nb:** 'comments.php' should return the content laid out as you wish it to be shown.
**nb:** the start param would be used in the limit statement on your db query.

```
function comments(ccount) {
  var ccount = (ccount == 'undefined' ? 1 : ccount);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'comments.php',
    data : {'start': ccount},
    success: function(data) {
      $('#comments').fadeOut('slow').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    }
  });
  setTimeout(function(){comments(ccount+1)},5000);
}
```

then in your docment ready just have
`comments();`